# Timer interrupt priority over TCPSocket Callbacks

Tags: interrupts, mbed, tcp-ip

I have a Timer Interrupt Routine which runs periodically (1000/sec). I plan on using mbed's TCPSocket  to receive incoming messages. For obvious reasons, this should not block.

It is essential that Timer Interrupt Routine takes priority over the TCPSocket Callback. How can I ensure this?

I suspect that this won't be a problem if the time taken to receive + time taken to run timer interrupt routine is less than 1/1000th sec. Is this correct?

I realise it's hard to estimate, but considering each "message" contains only 12 bytes, approximately how long would recv() take to transfer the data into a buffer? Microseconds?

Comment: Can you create a priority tree?

Comment: What controls the callback? WSAEventSelect() to register a waitable event for FD_READ ?

Comment: @Sparky256, I wouldn't know how to create such a thing...

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, I'm using the example at the bottom of the page: https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/network-socket.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interrupt+TCP+callback

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, Is there a way for the timer interrupt to interrupt the TCP callback function when needed, while ensuring that it cannot be itself interrupted by the callback function.

Comment: I understand interrupt priorities is a feature which exists in other frameworks, OSs, etc. Just can't seem to find any evidence it's possible with the mbed.

Comment: @Sparky256, please see updated question.